# Can I get a byte array From PDF image File with Podofo or libHaru?

Tags: c++, libharu, podofo

When I checked libharu and podofo, I checked the ability to save PDF files, but could not check the ability to load PDF and store them in a byte array.

Can I get a byte array From PDF image File with Podofo or libHaru?

If not, what is the proper library to open PDF and store it as a byte array? (except muPDF)

Comment: By 'byte array' do you mean some kind of bitmap image of the PDF, or do you literally mean the bytes in the PDF file?

Comment: bitmap image of the PDF file

Answer (score 0):

You mean to extract a bitmap image from a PDF file or to render PDF pages as images?
Neither libharu nor podofo has the capability to read PDF docs.
You should find a library that reads like [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/).